# error with Dynamic Resources-Token not valid

Tags: wpf, xaml, dictionary

I have a resource dictionary compiled for dynamic resources however I keep running into a problem. The app.xaml doesn't detect a problem with the dynamic resource buut the dictionary file keeps telling me "token not valid" I can't seem to figure out what is wrong. Especially because all the other dynamic values defined in the dictionary xaml work just fine. Code below.

From:Glass1.xaml (resource dictionary file)

```
<Color x:Key="BTBorderColor">Color="#8D8DEC</Color>
```

And the place it's used

```
 <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Brush_ButtonBorder" Color="{DynamicResource BTBorderColor}"/>
```

Key:BTBorderColor throws an error:Token not valid

However the next code that is used exactly the same way but with a different X:Key works perfectly fine. Any suggestions?

Comment: Remove the `Color="` from `<Color x:Key="BTBorderColor">Color="#8D8DEC</Color>`

Comment: Wow ok....I must be tired. I have the correct code written in another line right above it and didn't even notice my mistake. Thank you for pointing that out Bob.

Comment: No problem. We are all doing this kind of mistake ^^